# Is there a Tezos equivalent of Ganache?

Tags: testnet

In Ethereum, [Ganache](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache) is one of the most popular blockchain emulators used for local development purposes.

Is there an equivalent tool for Tezos?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Tezster-CLI](https://github.com/Tezsure/Tezster-CLI) to set up your local sandbox environment. You can use it along with [Bundle-react](https://github.com/Tezsure/Bundle-react) (Like truffle box) to deploy and test.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Tplus](https://tplus.dev/tplus), it's a  tool that helps you manage tezos environments ( sandboxes and public nodes ) for use for development on top of Tezos.